# combination of two lists in java

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations, probability

Is there any algorithm to achieve this combination of output?
Input :

```
arr1 = {x, y, z}
arr2 = {a, b}
```

Output :

```
xa, ya, za
xa, ya, zb
xa, yb, za
xa, yb, zb
xb, ya, za
xb, ya, zb
xb, yb, za
xb, yb, zb
```

Answer (score 3):

```
static char[] arr1 = {'x', 'y', 'z'};
static char[] arr2 = {'a', 'b'};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    print(new char[arr1.length - 1], 0);
}

static void print(char[] store, int depth) {
    for(char c : arr2) {
        if(depth < store.length) {
            store[depth] = c;
            print(store, depth + 1);
        } else {
            for(int i = 0; i < store.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(arr1[i] + "" + store[i] + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println(arr1[depth] + "" + c);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Couldn't resist trying out @DenisKulagin's method, so here goes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] arr1 = {'x', 'y', 'z'};
    char[] arr2 = {'a', 'b'};

    for(int i = 0; i < 1 << arr1.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
            int inverted = arr1.length - 1 - j;
            int index = (i & (1 << inverted)) >>> inverted;
            System.out.print(arr1[j] + "" + arr2[index] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Not quite as flexible as my version, since `arr2` can only contain 2 elements, but definitely a clever approach.

Answer (score 1):

1. Encode {a, a, a} as {0, 0, 0} - 0/binary.
2. Encode {b, b, b} as {1, 1, 1} - 7/binary.
3. Loop through 0..7, joining {x, y, z} & resulting 3-tuple.
4. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

It maybe a 2 power 3 (arr2.length power arr1.length). This should give the num of rows.

So you need an Algorithm that calculates every single row. The shorter one gives the num and the longer one the exponent.

Comment: It's not a Cartesian product

Comment: What else? You combine each item of list one with each item of list two. Am I wrong?

Comment: That would only yield 6 items.