# Java: Add all possible combinations of TRUE/FALSE to a list

Tags: java, loops, boolean, generator

I have seen other posts about this, but they are not exactly like this problem.

I have this code:

```
    public static List<Boosters.Builder> GetBoosters() {
    List<Boosters.Builder> boosters = new ArrayList<Boosters.Builder>();

    Boosters.Builder booster = new Boosters.Builder();

    booster.setLarge(Bool.TRUE).setMedium(Bool.TRUE).setSmall(Bool.TRUE);
    boosters.add(booster);

    booster.setLarge(Bool.FALSE).setMedium(Bool.TRUE).setSmall(Bool.FALSE);
    boosters.add(booster);

    booster.setLarge(Bool.TRUE).setMedium(Bool.FALSE).setSmall(Bool.TRUE);
    boosters.add(booster);

    booster.setLarge(Bool.TRUE).setMedium(Bool.TRUE).setSmall(Bool.FALSE);
    boosters.add(booster);

    // (etc, etc, etc)

    return boosters;
}
```

Which is a part of some generated types I am doing in Java. But Bool.TRUE/Bool.FALSE works sort of like normal java booleans so you can count on that.

I am trying to make a loop that will give me all possible combinations of TRUE/FALSE on:

```
booster.setLarge(Bool.TRUE).setMedium(Bool.TRUE).setSmall(Bool.TRUE);
```

I cannot figure out how to do this nicely in a loop. Can someone help me out?

Comment: How many values are you expected to need to assign? The problem to do it with loop (though it is possible) is that loops and inner loops run in polynomial time, while there are exponential (2^n) such assignments

Comment: Well I guess its Math.pow(2,3) for all possible values. setLarge(TRUE/FALSE), setMedium(TRUE/FALSE) and setSmall(TRUE,FALSE)? Or maybe its Math.pow(3,2), I am not good at this :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28472839/1553851

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Bool#values()` to iterate over possible values of your enum:

```
for (Bool large : Bool.values())
   for (Bool medium : Bool.values())
        for (Bool small : Bool.values())
              boosters.add(new Boosters.Builder().setLarge(large).setMedium(medium).setSmall(small));
```

Comment: Of course. So simple. Thanks a lot. Will accept when I can (timeout).

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to run an integer from `0` to `2^n` (exclusive) - where `n` is the number of variables you need to assign.

Then, you can use `(x >> k) % 2` to get the value of variable number k.

This works only for having less than 64 values (using `long` variables).

```
       for (int x =0; x < 1<<k; x++) { 
            int val1 = (x >> 0) %2;
            int val2 = (x >> 1) %2;
            int val3 = (x >> 2) %2;
            ...
            System.out.println("" + val1 + "," + val2 + "," + val3);
        }
```

Note that this approach can be easily modified to any number of variables (that fits in `long`) you have, by switching `val1,val2,...` to an array.